# Pause or Stop model using engine condition cause error

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to stop engine once target number reached using the following code:

```
if (self.count() >= Total_Input) {
    
    engine.pause();
    
   
}
```

but I having the following error:

```
engine cannot be resolved
```

I have checked Anylogic document and it seems to be straight forward in regards of stopping or pausing the model.

Can any one explain to me the error and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if anyone come across the `engine cannot be resolved` error, you need to use the `getEngine(). stop()` code.

```
  if (self.count() >= Total_Input) {
        
        getEngine().stop();
        
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method: there are 2 functions that can be called from anywhere without getting a reference to the engine: `pauseSimulation()` which is similar to pressing *pause* button in simulation controls and `finishSimulation()` which is equivalent to hitting *stop*.